# apache htaccess authentication based on query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, query-string

I'm using vanilla forums which already has these rewrite conditions and rules in .htaccess:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I would like now is to add some rewrite rules that ask for authentication (Require valid-user) only when I am on the page /vanilla/index.php?p=/categories/general, ie just the query string "p=/categories/general"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It isn't possible to add authentication based on the query string of a URL as far as I can 
tell.</strike>

Using `mod_rewrite`, you can only rewrite one URL to another, not specify additional configuration rules.

The [<Location>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) tag can be used to match a URL and require auth, but `Location` cannot match query strings so it won't work in your case.

Is there a reason you need to use `.htaccess` authentication?  Could you build the logic into the PHP script easily?

Comment: I have found different possibilities online, but I couldn't make any of them work for my setup. This was one way I found, though it didn't work. When I wrote the directory path I got server error 500, and without the directory tag I couldn't get the script to trigger.

(from http://www.lucidiocy.com/2010/07/query-string-based-apache.html)

Comment: Interesting concept, I wasn't able to make it work though.  The 500 error is because `<Directory>` sections are not allowed in `.htaccess` files, only in `httpd.conf` and within vhosts.  I tried some other combinations but wasn't able to make it work 100% of the time.  From reading the comments, even the author of that post wasn't able to get it to work in the end, which is the same problem I was having I think.  Could be that I'm testing on Apache 2.4 which changed a lot in regards to auth from version 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply drew. According to #apache on irc.freenode.net it should be possible, but it is quite a hassle for me to learn all the apache requirements for this small thing. Hope it will work out eventually.

Comment: Actually on http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php you can find nice examples on how to do that, with both Basic and Digest methods. Worth a read!